# React state update issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I try to add new arrays and values in a state.
I'm using react-beautiful-dnd to display this state datas.

my initial state :

```
 const initialData = {
            users: {
                'user-1': { id: 'user-1', name: 'John'},
                'user-2': { id: 'user-2', name: 'Patrick'},
                'user-3': { id: 'user-3', name: 'Malorie'},
                'user-4': { id: 'user-4', name: 'Eric'},
                'user-5': { id: 'user-5', name: 'Bob'},
                'user-6': { id: 'user-6', name: 'Blob'}
            },
            areas: {
                'area-0': {
                    id: 'area-0',
                    title: 'Main Area',
                    userIds: ['user-1', 'user-2','user-3', 'user-4','user-5', 'user-6']
                },
                'area-1': {
                    id: 'area-1',
                    title: 'Area 1',
                    userIds: []
                },
                'area-2': {
                    id: 'area-2',
                    title: 'Area 2',
                    userIds: []
                }
            },
            areaOrder: ['area-0','area-1', 'area-2'],
        }
 
 class MyClass {
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        data: initialData,
      }
   }
 ...
 }
```

I have a dropdown menu to choose the number of areas I want to display in total, when I trigger it, I try to add the new areas in the 'areas' array and in 'areOrder' array.
If I update the number of areas again, I need to reset the state to 'initialData'.

the code in MyClass:

```
 // apply is triggered by the dropdown menu
 apply = (numOfAreas) => {
     // clear state to initial data
     this.setState({
        data: initialData
    })
 
    for (let i = 3; i <= numOfBOR; i++ ) {
        this.addNewArea(i);
    }
 }
 
 addNewArea = (newRoomId) => {
    const areas = { ...this.state.data.areas };
    let p = "area-";
    let key = newAreaId;
    const newAreaKey = p.concat(key);
    const areaTitle = "Area ".concat(newAreaId);

    let obj = [];
    obj[newAreaKey] = { id: newAreaKey, title: areaTitle, userIds: [] };

    const currentAreas = { ...areas };
    const newAreaObj = Object.assign(currentAreas, obj);

    const newState = {
      ...this.state.data,
      areas: newAreaObj,
      areaOrder: [...this.state.data.areaOrder, newAreaKey]
    };
    this.setState({data: newState});
  };
```

When I use the code above, only the last area is displayed(i.e. when I chose 8 areas, the area 8 is display after area 2)
I'm aware that setState is asynch, so I'd like to know which method will allow me to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `setState` doesn't use previous state, so each `setState` change `areas` to its initial value plus one new element. You can use `this.setState(prevState => newState)` to get previous state.

Comment: I tried this way:
this.setState(prevState => ({
            ...this.state.data,
            areas: [...prevState.areas, newState],
            areaOrder: [...prevState.areaOrder, newAreaKey]
        }));
but getting a preState.areas is not iterable script error

Comment: It's a bad idea to update state in for loop. Try to use `setState` once. In your apply function get `areas` and `areaOrder` from current state, modify them in for loop and then call `setState` once.

Comment: Also, you don't need "clear" state before changing.